# Pgfplots Interrupt Bounding Box by applying a style to a node

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, tikz-node, bounding-box

I would like to be able to use

```
\addplot ... node {<node text>};
```

and have the node *not* affect the bounding box.  That is, the bounding box should be what it would be with just:

```
\addplot ... ;
```

The ideal solution (see code for third graph) would be to have a style `Interrupt Bounding Box` and use it as

```
\addplot ... node [Interrupt Bounding Box] {<node text>};
```

A failed solution (see code for second graph) was of the form:

```
 \addplot ... ;
 \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
     \addplot [draw=none] ... node {<node text>};
 \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
```

but I really would prefer to not have to do the `\addplot` twice if possible.

The MWE below produces the following:

[image]

The first graph is the desired bounding box size.

### Use Case:

I have a macro that does all the graphing of functions which accepts a graph label (that is to be placed at the end of a graph). If the given graph label is empty I would like that to not affect the bounding box. I could of course do this with something like

```
    \IfStrEq{\GraphLabel}{}{%
       \addplot ... ;
    }{
       \addplot ... node {<node text>};
    }
```

which I might resort to, but don't like that I have to duplicate the `\addplot` twice.

Another failed case (not included in the MWE) was of the form

```
    \IfStrEq{\GraphLabel}{}{%
       \def\NodeCode{}%
    }{
       \def\NodeCode{node {<node text>}}%
    }

    \addplot ... \NodeCode;
```

This works for the case there is only invocation my macro that does the graphing. I suspect the problem with this approach is related to the `nodes` being drawn at the end of the `axis` environment.

### References:

- [Fix bounding box in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278255/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30cm]{geometry}% so graphs all fit side-bys-side
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\DrawBoundingBox}{%
    \draw [draw=blue, thin]
        (current bounding box.south west)
        rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east)
}%

\newcommand*{\GraphLabel}{$y = x^2$}

\pgfplotsset{My Axis Style/.style={
    axis lines=middle, 
    clip=false,
}}
\pgfplotsset{My Plot Style/.style={
    mark=none,
    domain=-2:2,
    draw=red, thick,
    x=1cm, y=1cm,
}}

\tikzset{Interrupt Bounding Box/.style={
    %% ???? This would be ideal solution, but not sure how to do this.
}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[My Axis Style]
        \addplot [My Plot Style] ({x},{x*x});
    \end{axis}
    
    \DrawBoundingBox;
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[My Axis Style]
        \addplot [My Plot Style] ({x},{x*x});
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \addplot [My Plot Style, draw=none] ({x},{x*x})% <---  Style Modified
                node [above=5pt] {\GraphLabel};
         \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \end{axis}
   
    \useasboundingbox
        (current axis.below south west)
        rectangle
        (current axis.above north east);
    
    \DrawBoundingBox;
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[My Axis Style]
        \addplot [My Plot Style] ({x},{x*x})
            node [above=5pt, Interrupt Bounding Box] {\GraphLabel} ;
    \end{axis}
    
    \DrawBoundingBox;
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strictly limited to your use case: With `\addplot [My Plot Style] ({x},{x*x}) \ifx\@empty\GraphLabel\else node [above=5pt] {\GraphLabel} \fi;` you would not have to type `\addplot` twice.

Comment: `node {\smash{\raisebox{5pt}{\GraphLabel}}}` is not a `pgfplots` solution, but it works for your usecase.

Comment: `\tikzset{Interrupt Bounding Box/.style={overlay}}`? What I want to say is that `overlay` issues a `\pgfinterruptboundingbox` AFAIK.

Comment: @schtandard: Yeah, `\smash` works, but does require one to account for the specific style applied to the node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your aim correctly, you are looking for `overlay`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} % <- not important HERE and NOW but good to add IMHO
\newcommand{\DrawBoundingBox}{%
    \draw [draw=blue, thin]
        (current bounding box.south west)
        rectangle
        (current bounding box.north east)
}%

\newcommand*{\GraphLabel}{$y = x^2$}

\pgfplotsset{My Axis Style/.style={
    axis lines=middle, 
    clip=false,
}}
\pgfplotsset{My Plot Style/.style={
    mark=none,
    domain=-2:2,
    draw=red, thick,
    x=1cm, y=1cm,
}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[My Axis Style]
        \addplot [My Plot Style] ({x},{x*x})
            node [above=5pt, overlay] {\GraphLabel} ;
    \end{axis}

    \DrawBoundingBox;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works great. It did not occur to me to try `overlay` on a `node`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I think I learned this from percusse, if I remember correctly.